# Default initialize arbitrary bounded type of boost variant and optional

Tags: c++, boost, variant, option-type

Default constructor of boost variant initializes the first bounded type. How do I default initialize any member other than the first? One option is to simply assign a default constructed object of the right type. However, that does not work with some types like arrays. Without initialization `boost::get` throws `boost::bad_get` exception. So I can't  do `std::copy` on the array.

```
boost::variant<std:string, int[5]> v; // default initializes the string.
```

I need something like

```
initialize<int[5]>(v);
```

I also had compilation issues when using an array as the first bounded type. Clang reports error as follows:

```
object expression of non-scalar type 'int [5]' cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression 
  operand.~T();
```

**Edit:** I've the same question regarding boost.optional. Is there an API to default initialize an optional? I mean other than an assignment from a default initialized T.

Comment: It seems variant requires each bounded type to be CopyConstructible or MoveConstructible, which arrays are not (in C++03 at least).

Comment: Using the InPlaceFactory and TypedInPlaceFactory for boost.optional I can do default initialization. Pretty cool! Boost variant, however, does not seem to support the InPlaceFactory idiom.